# Generating constant via preprocessor macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'd like to create a macro that spits out an existent constant.

There are multiple constants and they all follow the form `PREFIX_COMPONENT_ERROR`.

Example code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {
  MODULE_ERROR_COMP1_ERROR1 = 0,
  MODULE_ERROR_COMP1_ERROR2,
  MODULE_ERROR_COMP1_ERROR3,
  MODULE_ERROR_COMP2_ERROR1,
  MODULE_ERROR_COMP2_ERROR2,
  MODULE_ERROR_COMP2_ERROR3,
};

static void* some_function (const char *restrict input);

#define EMPTY(...)
#define DEFER(...) __VA_ARGS__ EMPTY()
#define OBSTRUCT(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER(EMPTY)()
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PASTER(x, y) x ## _ ## y

#define MODULE_ERROR some_function ("module error")

#define ERROR_PREFIX DEFER(MODULE_ERROR)
#define GENERATE_ERROR_(prefix, component, error) PASTER(DEFER(PASTER(prefix, component)), error)
#define GENERATE_ERROR(prefix, component, error) EXPAND(GENERATE_ERROR_(prefix, component, error))

static void* some_function (const char *restrict input) {
  /*
   * Does something with the input and returns some data,
   * but for simplicity let's assume it just passes the input through.
   */
  return (input);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  /* Generate enum via PP macros, for instance: */
  for (size_t i = 0; 3 > i; ++i) {
    int error_code = 0;
    void *common_error = ERROR_PREFIX;

    if (0 == i) {
      error_code = GENERATE_ERROR (ERROR_PREFIX, COMP1, ERROR1);
    }
    else if (1 == i) {
      error_code = GENERATE_ERROR (ERROR_PREFIX, COMP2, ERROR3);
    }
    else {
      error_code = GENERATE_ERROR (ERROR_PREFIX, COMP2, ERROR2);
    }

    /* Do something with error_code and common_error. */
  }

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I wonder if what I want to do is even possible with simple PP directives in the first place.

The first issue is that I cannot use the concatenation macro `PASTER` twice, because the PP always chokes on the inner `PASTER()` call.

Converting that to a three-parameter macro such as:

```c
#define PASTER(x, y, z) x ## _ ## y ## _ ## z

#define GENERATE_ERROR_(prefix, component, error) PASTER(prefix, component, error)
```

will expand `prefix`, which I do not want to happen and will run into an error anyway.

Using something like `PASTER(OBSTRUCT(prefix), component, error)` will likewise fail on concatenation.

I'm fully aware that this WOULD work, but I don't like it:

```c
#define MODULE_ERROR_FUNC some_function ("module error")

#define ERROR_PREFIX MODULE_ERROR
#define GENERATE_ERROR_(prefix, component, error) PASTER(prefix, component, error)
#define GENERATE_ERROR(prefix, component, error) GENERATE_ERROR_(prefix, component, error)

/* [...] */
    void *common_error = MODULE_ERROR_FUNC;
```

Is there really no way to let `ERROR_PREFIX` be expanded only once in the `GENERATE_ERROR` macro  (i.e., to `MODULE_ERROR`) and otherwise have it expand to the function call (i.e., `some_function ("module error")`)?

Comment: What's wrong with `#define GENERATE_ERROR(prefix, component, error) prefix ## _ ## component ## _ ## error`  — and then invoking `GENERATE_ERROR(MODULE_PREFIX, COMP1, ERROR1)`?

Comment: That would work, I guess, because concatenation disables further expansion and there is no indirection that would force it. My intention was to avoid having to use the full prefix in my case, though, because it's so long and shortening via another macro would be beneficial. It's not obvious in this example, but when the prefix is something like `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR` you'd like to avoid typing it all the time, especially if you use macros internally anyway.

Comment: Can you not use `#define GENERR(component, error) GENERATE_ERROR(PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR, component, error)` to shorten the long names — invoking `GENERR(COMPONENT2, ERROR2)` to get `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2` as the error name?

Comment: Yep, that seems to work. If you'd like to add this as a proper answer and maybe also explain why `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR` won't be expanded during the expansion of `GENERR` (i.e., why is it painted blue in that context?) I'd accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate reaction to seeing your question was "you're over-complicating it!"  For example, what's wrong with:

```
#define GENERATE_ERROR(prefix, component, error) prefix ## _ ## component ## _ ## error
```

and then invoking:

```
GENERATE_ERROR(MODULE_PREFIX, COMP1, ERROR1)
```

One partial answer to "what's the problem?" is that "it's not obvious in this example, but when the prefix is something like `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR` you'd like to avoid typing it all the time".  Which is OK, but then you could consider:

```
#define GENERR(component, error) GENERATE_ERROR(PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR, component, error)
```

to shorten the long names — invoking

```
GENERR(COMPONENT2, ERROR2)
```

to get the error name:

```
PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2
```

> Why won't `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR` be expanded during the expansion of `GENERR` (i.e., why is it painted blue in that context)?

It isn't painted blue; I just wouldn't create a macro with that name so there'd be nothing for it to expand to — just like there shouldn't be a macro `COMPONENT2` or `ERROR2` that can be expanded when `GENERR` is invoked.

---

#### Experimentation

Consider the source file `pp31.c`:

```
#define GENERATE_ERROR(prefix, component, error) prefix ## _ ## component ## _ ## error
GENERATE_ERROR(MODULE_PREFIX, COMP1, ERROR1)    -- OK

#define GENERR(component, error) GENERATE_ERROR(PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR, component, error)
GENERR(COMPONENT2, ERROR2)                      -- OK

#define PLS_ERR PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR

#undef GENERR
#define GENERR(component, error) GENERATE_ERROR(PLS_ERR, component, error)
GENERR(COMPONENT2, ERROR2)                      -- Broken

#undef GENERR
#define GENERR_PREFIX(prefix, component, error) GENERATE_ERROR(prefix, component, error)
#define GENERR(component, error) GENERR_PREFIX(PLS_ERR, component, error)
GENERR(COMPONENT2, ERROR2)                      -- OK

#define PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR pink_elephant
GENERR(COMPONENT2, ERROR2)                      -- Broken (too many pink elephants)

#undef PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR
#define GENCOMPERR(err) GENERATE_ERROR(PLS_ERR, COMPONENT2, err)
GENCOMPERR(ERROR2)                              -- Broken

#undef GENCOMPERR
#define GENCOMPERR(err) GENERR(COMPONENT2, err)
GENCOMPERR(ERROR2)                              -- OK

#undef GENCOMPERR
#define CURR_COMP COMPONENT2
#define GENCOMPERR(err) GENERATE_ERROR(PLS_ERR, CURR_COMP, err)
GENCOMPERR(ERROR2)                              -- Broken

#undef GENCOMPERR
#define GENCOMPERR(err) GENERR_PREFIX(PLS_ERR, CURR_COMP, err)
GENCOMPERR(ERROR2)                              -- OK
```

When I run `cpp pp31.c` (this is the `cpp` from GCC 9.3.0 running on a Mac), I get a few more blank lines than are shown below, but the non-blank lines are the interesting ones anyway:

```
# 1 "pp31.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "pp31.c"

MODULE_PREFIX_COMP1_ERROR1 -- OK

PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- OK

PLS_ERR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- Broken

PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- OK

pink_elephant_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- Broken (too many pink elephants)

PLS_ERR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- Broken

PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- OK

PLS_ERR_CURR_COMP_ERROR2 -- Broken

PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR_COMPONENT2_ERROR2 -- OK
```

The key point is that (with care), you can have macros that expand to the elements of the final concatenated error message name (hence `PLS_ERR` and `CURR_COMP`), but you cannot have macros for those elements (no 'pink elephants').

---

I reserve judgement on whether this is truly a good design for handling error message names, but I think it can be made to work.

Comment: The part I do not understand is that my compiler/preprocessor (part of GCC 8.3.0) does not expand `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR` even though it *is* a macro for `pink_elefant` (or `some_function(...)`). Likewise, the `PLS_ERR` example won't work directly because `PLS_ERR` is not getting expanded. I haven't yet understood why that is the case.

Comment: No arrogance implied. If I read ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 6.10 correctly, `GENERR(a, b)` should be substituted as such: `GENERATE_ERROR(PLS_ERR, a, b)` → `GENERATE_ERROR(PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR, a, b)` → `PROJECT_LONG_SUBMODULE_ERROR ## _ ## a ## _ ## b` because arguments and other parameters are substituted before other function-like macros, but this doesn't seem to happen. The indirection SHOULD create a new expansion context, but that doesn't seem to be true and I cannot find any (obvious?) reason in the C99 standard.

Comment: I've put together a file `pp31.c` which is in the answer with numerous variations on the theme, some of which work, some of which don't (and which is which is documented, and illustrated).  I hope the extra information helps.